# superscripts does not show properly on an image created by itext on pdf

Tags: unicode, awt, itext, jfreechart, graphics2d

I have a very confusing problem about unicode support in the generated pie chart in my pdf.
Here is what I have:
I am generating pie chart (with jfreechart library) that need to add superscripts on the title of the pie chart. 
I tested and I know that jfreechart is generating correct title (superscripts are fine) and I also tested itext unicode support.
There is a Graphics2D (from java awt) in between which turns the jfreechart into a template and then I can print this template into my pdf.
according my tests I guess problem should be in between graphics2d and itext template.

`PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();`

`PdfTemplate template = canvas.createTemplate(width, height);`

`FontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();`

`template.setFontAndSize(mapper.awtToPdf(new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 7)) , 7);`

`Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height);`

`graphics2d.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 7));`

`JFreeChart chart = getPieChart("", title, value);`

---

I found out the problem.
Problem is template (PdfTemplate) does not show the unicode character. Although I embedded unicode fonts and set it for template, still not working.
any ideas?

Comment: Is `"Arial Unicode MS"` accessible to the JVM? What happens if you specify `Font. SANS_SERIF`?

Comment: That's a good question. I wrote a test class and tested Arial Unicode Ms and it worked. but that was simple class I am not sure if it is supported when I build the project.and I never tested SANS_SERIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually finally I fixed the problem by removing superscript from pie chart and print it directly into template. This also eliminates the use of unicode font (which costs extra money):

`template.beginText();`

`template.setFontAndSize(arial, 8);`

`// the fixed position of the xy coordinate that I want to print  superscript`
`template.moveText(97, 142);`

`template.showText(superscript);`

`template.setTextRise(5f);`

`template.endText();`